# "One in 5, one in 50, two in 600,000" - can this be called a Geulah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yetziat-mitzrayim, bo

Different Midrashim give different estimates on the number of Jews actually exiting Egypt, ranging from one in 5 (חמושים) and up to 2 in 600,000, the rest dying in the Plague of Darkness.

I was trying to explain this to my son, just picture it, say the Moshiah is coming tomorrow and out of 6M Jews in Israel anything from 5M to 5.999999M die and the rest have all the fun of the Geulah.

This does not sound so much of a Geulah, for that was exactly Moses claim not to kill Jews in the desert when G-d offered to "re-start" the Jewish nation from Moses. Even if those 80-99% were called wicked, how bad could they be if they all were idolaters etc.

This does not make sense to me. Please help.

Comment: Who says that these are to be taken literally?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Offer your version, metaphorically. Who died in 3 days of darkness? Who did they bury?

Comment: There are those who say that the 80% means counting all the Bnai Yisrael who died during the 210 years. Consider the numbers. 600,000 men survived means that there were 3,000,000 originally (2,400,000) died. How many people actually lived in Egypt and the meaning of the midrash is not accepted by everyone.

Comment: @AlBerko what non-Midrashic source do you have that states that anyone died in the three days of darkness?  Or that they buried people?  What the Midrash mean is that there were a small number of very evi Jews (Reshaim) who died at some point during the Makkos (during Choshech according to other Midrashim), and the 1 in 5/50/500 comes from the Passuk (13:18) **Vachamushim** Alu Benei Yisrael...  The point the Midrash makes is that this itself was a huge Simcha that these evil people had died! (which is why it is quoted on the words "Vayikdu Haam Vayishtachavu")

Comment: The literal reading of all of these Midrashim together is potentially absurd (which it is good that you have noticed).  Do you think the Egyptians would not have noticed that only 20%, 2% or 0.2% or less of the Jews were remaining after Choshech, if the whole point of them dying during Choshech was for the Egyptians not to notice...  But wait for an answer which I will IY"H post.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here is the text of this Midrash (this version is from Tanchuma Beshalach):

> וחמשים עלו בני ישראל אחד מחמשה, ויש אומרים אחד מחמשים, ויש אומרים אחד מחמש מאות, רבי נהוראי אומר העבודה לא אחד מחמשת אלפים, ואימתי מתו בימי האפלה שהיו קוברין ישראל מתיהן ומצרים יושבין בחשך, ישראל הודו ושבחו על שלא ראו שונאיהם ושמחו בפורענותן

This Midrash about large numbers of Jews dying before leaving Egypt, can be explained literally according to some of the opinions found in the Midrashim (like 1 in 5, maybe even 1 in 50), by some Mefarshim (see Sabbahillel's comments above, and Oznaim Latorah).  However, in this case, it has already been noted by Rishonim that the question is better than the answer, and that in fact, taking this literally will undermine the entire Nes of Yetzias Mitzraiyim, as well as go against a number of Pesukim.

My answer (in the comments as well) was that this was simply a Derasha based on the words Vachamushim, and really many fewer people died.  However, [Isaac Hirsch Weiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Hirsch_Weiss) in his [Peirush Midos Sofrim Beshalach 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33719&st=&pgnum=96) (which is meant to be a Peshat explanation of the Mechilta?), the idea of exaggeration is refuted, as he feels that a Lashon of Shevuah (made by Rabbi Nehorai) would be inappropriate unless that person though that they were telling the exact truth.  (He notes there that according to the version that we have in the Tanchuma, this would mean that there were about 3 Billion Jews in Egypt, which is obviously impossible, and he admits he cannot understand this Midrash.)

Ibn Ezra to Shemos 13:18 says that this opposes the entire concept of Yetzias Mitzrayim, I have bolded various points below.  He concludes that perhaps the one who said it intended it with some deeper meaning, (although he does not offer what it may be):

> **ודרש (מכילתא שמות י״ג:י״ח): שעלו אחד מחמש מאות, דבר יחיד הוא, ועליו מחלוקת, ואיננו קבלה כלל**. ודי לנו הצער שאנחנו בו עם חכמי ישמעאל, שהם אומרים: איך יתכן מחמשים וחמשה זכרים, שיולידו במאתים ועשר שנים שש מאות אלף זכרים מבן עשרים. והנה היו כפל הכפל עם הטף והנשים, כי לא חשבו יעקב ובניו, כי לא הולידו במצרים עוד, כי לא מצאנו יחוש רק אל היורדים מצרימה, ולא ספרו הבנות. ותשובתנו: כי הנה יעקב לבדו הוליד בארבעים שנה ושש שנים תשעה וששים בנים ובני בנים, ועל זה המספר יכפלו עד שיהיו כפלי כפלים מהמספר הכתוב. אז השיבו לנו עוד: כי יעקב ובניו לא הולידו נקבות כי אם שתים, וזה היה במעשה נס, ואל תספור כן ליורדי מצרים. ועוד שיעקב היו לו ארבע נשים, ומי יבאר שכן היו לכל אחד מבני בניו. גם אנחנו השיבונו: תנו לנו שלשה עשר זכרים, בין בנים ובני בנים, בארבעים ושש שנים, והנה יהיו יותר מן שבע מאות, ובסוף תשעים ושנים יהיו תשעת אלפים ושלש מאות, ובסוף מאה ושלשים ושמונה יהיו יותר ממאת אלף, ובסוף מאה ושמונה ושתים יהיו יותר מאלף אלפים וחמש מאות אלף, ועוד לא הגענו למאתים ועשר שנים. גם יתנו לנו עשרה בארבעים ושש שנים, ויספיקו. **ועוד כי הכתוב אומר על מכת ערוב: ושמתי פדות בין עמי ובין עמך (שמות ח׳:י״ט).** ואמר בספר תהלות: ישלח בם ערוב ויאכלם (תהלים ע״ח:מ״ה). **והנה במכה שאכלה את מצרים נמלט ישראל, גם מת רוב מקנה מצרים בדבר, וממקנה ישראל לא מת אחד (שמות ט׳:ו׳)**, **ובמכת בכורים לא מת מישראל אחד**, **ובמכת חושך כתיב: ולכל בני ישראל היה אור (שמות י׳:כ״ג).** **והנה במכות שמתו בהם המצריים לא מתו ישראלים,** ואף כי במכה שלא מת מצרי ממנה. **ואיך מתו כל ישראל בחשך עד שלא נשאר מהם רק חלק מחמש מאות. והנה לא היה לישראל אור במושבותם,1 רק מחשכי דבר ואפלות מות. ואחר שלא נשאר כי אם חלק קטון מעם רב, הנה לא היתה גאולה לישראל כי אם רעה חולה, וזה הפך הכתוב.** והכלל: דרש הוא, ואין לסמוך עליו, **אולי שאמרו בתחילה היה לנו סוד**.

Rabbeinu Bachya/Bechayei (same link as Ibn Ezra) explains the Midrash as each of these numbers (one in 5, 50, or 500) to balance the later Midrash of Veshalishim al Kulo (3 or 30 or 300 Egyptians per Jew), to equal 900 million "Angels of harm" that Hashem came down with, so that there would be 900 million Egyptians chasing the Jews according to each opinion:

> וע״ד המדרש וחמשים עלו אחד מחמשה וארבעה חלקים מתו בג׳ ימי החשך כדי שלא יראו המצריים בפורענותן, ויש אומרים אחד מחמשים ויש אומרים אחד מחמש מאות מכאן ואילך צא וחשוב. ושלשים על כלו, יש אומרים יצאו עליהם ג׳ מצריים על כל אחד ואחד מישראל ויש אומרים שלשים ויש אומרים ג׳ מאות, ע״כ במדרש.
> ובאור הענין כי מי שאומר אחד מחמשה א״כ היו תחלה ישראל ה׳ פעמים ס׳ רבוא שהם שלש מאות רבוא ודעתו כי ושלשים על כולו באורו שלש מאות מצריים על כלו על כל אחד ואחד מישראל, ויעלה העם תשעים אלף רבוא שיצאו המצריים עליהם, וכן מצינו במדרש כשירד הקב״ה למצרים ירדו תשעים אלף רבוא של מלאכי חבלה במחנה מצרים. ומי שאמר אחד מחמשים היו ישראל ג׳ אלף רבוא ודעתו כי ושלשים באורו שלשים על כל אחד ואחד הרי ל׳ פעמים ג׳ אלף רבוא הם תשעים אלף רבוא. ומי שאומר אחד מחמש מאות היו ישראל תחלה שלשים אלף רבוא ודעתו כי ושלשים ג׳ על כל אחד ואחד והם תשעים אלף רבוא. הרי חשבון כל החכמים מכוון שיצאו המצריים עליהם בתשעים אלף רבוא בין למי שאומר אחד מחמשה בין למי שאומר אחד מחמשים בין למי שאומר אחד מחמש מאות עם צרוף החשבון ושלשים על כלו לפי דעתו וסברתו של כל אחד מהם וכנגדן הוציא עליהם הקב״ה תשעים אלף מלאכי חבלה זה באור המדרש הזה. ותמצא מלת וחמשים חסר וא״ו וחמשים כתיב ללמדך שהתורה שנתנה לחמשים יום היתה תכלית מה שעלו בני ישראל מארץ מצרים, ועוד יש בו רמז לחמשים פעמים שנזכרה יציאת מצרים בתורה. )

What comes from all of this, is that teaching such a Midrash as actual, factual Peshat is harmful to the story of Yetzias Mitzrayim, and should be avoided.

Comment: _"taking this literally will undermine the entire Nes of Yetzias Mitzraiyim"_ - exactly my point, why would the Midrash need such interpretation in the first place? What's the point of killing most of the Jewish people prior to the Exodus?

Comment: @AlBerko please reread my answer.

Comment: Please don't tease me. My question is not about numbers, but the very idea of killing the vast majority of the people does not look as the promised redemption to me.

Comment: @Alberko I'm not teasing, just a bit frustrated. **The idea of killing the vast majority of people was not suggested as a historical fact.** (If you still wish to take it as one, there can be ways to rationally explain the Shitah of 1 in 5, but no further.) The idea is that they were a chosen nation leaving Egypt, Hashem had killed off all of the bad people in their midst, leaving the good people.  No huge massacre took place just before they left Egypt.

Comment: It does not matter for me, be it real or metaphorical. What's the point of this killing even metaphorically? Does it teaches us the greatness of G-d? How come 99% of Jews became hopelessly wicked, beyond the level of Erev Rav? הן גאלתי אתכם אחרית כראשית - is that what awaits us all in the upcoming Geulah?